# Redis lua scripting - What is the python equivalent of the lua script written in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, redis

I do not know ruby but I know python.  What is the python equivalent for running the below code?  This example was taken from the redis website.  So, what is this?

```
<<EOF?
```

would it be in python:

```
  RandomPushScript = """
    Lua code here
   """


RandomPushScript = <<EOF
    local i = tonumber(ARGV[1])
    local res
    math.randomseed(tonumber(ARGV[2]))
    while (i > 0) do
        res = redis.call('lpush',KEYS[1],math.random())
        i = i-1
    end
    return res
EOF

r.del(:mylist)
puts r.eval(RandomPushScript,1,:mylist,10,rand(2**32))
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362/164572)

Comment: Sorry, "the Lua script written in Ruby"?? Lua and Ruby are different languages, and Python is yet a third.

Comment: @DanielRoseman As seen above, it is a Ruby script that appears to create a Lua script as a big string, and then does something with it.

Comment: There is very little documentation for lua scripting with redis.  The documentation that does exists; it uses ruby to pass a lua function to redis. For python programmers, it would be great if there was a python example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<<` indicates a HereDoc. After it there is a marker (here `EOF`). The next lines are a string, until the marker appears again.
So yes, `"""` would be the Python equivalent.

Comment: For the python dudes....here is the example found after I posted this questions.  http://iam.richardbucker.com/2012/01/18/redis-eval-in-2-6-0/